# Multiple primary key understanding

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i want to add 2 primary key, let's suppose that those column are "A" and "B", if I do :

```
select * from my_table where A="value"
```

I can have multiple results.

Same for column B

So we get only one value when having both Column A and Column B (Also when inserting, we need column A and B not null)

So my questions : How to do this in a mySQL database.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: You don't. You can only have 1 primary key. That's why it's called **primary**.

Comment: A table can never have more than 1 primary key. However, the primary key can consist of several columns. (And a table can have unique constraints.)

Comment: I believe you are asking about `composite key`.

Comment: Yes I mean one primary key, but it's a couple of column, is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many columns in a primary key as you want. 
Example: CONSTRAINT [PK_TableName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Column1], [Column1],...),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is standard SQL. It's not specific to MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  A INT NOT NULL,
  B INT NOT NULL,
  C INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (A, B)
);
```